# How to delete record from table having same id and name?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I have table AddClient

```
Id   cId  name amount
10L CL-J Jon   5000
10L CL-B Ben   4000
10L CL-J Jon   6000 
10L CL-B Ben   8000
10L CL-T Tony  9000
10L CL-J Jon   5000
```

When I try to delete the record like this

```
DELETE from AddClient where cId = 'CL-J' or name = 'Jon'
```

it Deletes all records of Jon. I want to delete just one record of Jon.

Comment: So, which one do you want to delete?

Comment: You need `cId = 'CL-J' and name = 'Jon'`.

Comment: Well, which one are you wanting to delete?

Comment: MySQL or sqlite? Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Please show expected result

Comment: I want to delete "CL-J  Jon 5000" and i'm using Sqlite

Comment: Why `5000` and why not `6000`

Comment: @Prdp because  the amount values may be same in future

Answer (score 1):

One obvious solution is to use `AND` rather than `OR`:

```
DELETE FROM AddClient
    WHERE cId = 'CL-J' AND name = 'Jon';
```

This will still result in deleting two records, so it is not exactly what you want.  But the logic seems clearer (to an outsider).

If your SQLite has the functionality enabled, then you can use:

```
DELETE FROM AddClient
    WHERE cId = 'CL-J' AND name = 'Jon'
    LIMIT 1;
```

(Read [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) about the optional `LIMIT` clause for `DELETE`.)

Another option is to use `rowid`:

```
DELETE FROM AddClient
    WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid)
                   FROM AddClient
                   WHERE cId = 'CL-J' AND name = 'Jon'
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you say "I want to delete just one record of Jon." You need to specify which other attribute (column) of the tuple (row) you wish to delete. The problem with using an `AND` operator is that **ALL** of the rows that have the name attribute of 'John' also have the cId attribute of 'CL-J' so, in effect, you are still deleting the same amount of rows as you would if you used an `OR` operator.

I also observe that the `Id` columns are identical as well for **ALL** records with name 'John', the only differentiating column is `amount`. Therefore, if you truly wish to delete only one record of John, you're **ONLY** option is the following:

```
DELETE 
FROM AddClient
WHERE name = 'John'
AND amount = 6000;
```

I hope this helps you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Mysql

```
DELETE FROM AddClient WHERE NAME='john' LIMIT 1;
```

or you can also delete single record on the basis of amount b/c amount differs of each record.....

```
DELETE 
FROM AddClient
WHERE name = 'John'
AND amount = '5000';
```